# NSString containing sql query in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have a sql query which looks like this -

```
NSString *createSQL = @"SELECT ingredients, recipe FROM drinktable where title like '%_drinkName%'";
```

Also **_drinkName** is a variable. What is the correct syntax of writing this in objective-c ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming _drinkName is an NSString, try:

```
NSString *createSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ingredients, recipe FROM drinktable WHERE title LIKE '%%%@%%'", _drinkName];
```

(Note that each of your %'s needs to be doubled.  And the %@ is for the string format parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

Because NSString is an object, you can use `stringWithFormat` to replace the `%@` specifier with another string

```
NSString *createSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT ingredients, recipe FROM drinktable where title like '%@'", _drinkName];
```

This will replace `%@` with the value of _drinkName